# How to make the legend box transparent in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

The legend box is covering parts of the graph (even though I removed the borders). How do I make the legend box transparent?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can add `fill=none` to the `legend style` key as in this approach.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend style={fill=none}
    ]
      \addplot {x};
      \addlegendentry{$x$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Repositioning the legend or decrease of its font size could also be an option.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. No need to reposition or decrease font size now!